# How to find Frechet derivate for this functional

Tags: partial-differential-equations, frechet-derivative

My functional is $F(u)=\frac{1}{2}\int (|D_x u|^2 + |D_y u|^2)dxdy + \int fu  dxdy$ where $f\in C(\Omega)$, $u\in C_{0}^2(\overline{\Omega})$ and $\Omega \subset R^2$. Well Im reading Elliptic problems in Nonsmooth domains (P.Grisvard) page 2, my question is i need to compute $F(u+\delta)-F(u)$ and try to find some residuous linear in $\delta$? And $\delta$ need to depend of $x,y$? Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let $u_0, h \in \mathcal{C}^2(\bar{\Omega})$. Then
\begin{align}
F(u+h) &= \frac{1}{2}\int (|D_x (u+h|)^2 + |D_y (u+h)|^2)dxdy + \int f(u+h)  dxdy \\
&= \frac{1}{2}\int (|D_x u|^2+\langle D_xu,D_xh \rangle +|D_xh|^2  + |D_y u|^2+\langle D_yu,D_yh \rangle +|D_yh|^2)dxdy\\&~~~~~+  \int (fu + fh)  dxdy \\
&= F(u) + \frac12\int\left(\langle D_xu,D_xh \rangle + \langle D_yu,D_yh \rangle  +fh \right)dxdy + \frac12\int |D_xh|^2+|D_yh|^2dxdy \\
&= F(u) + l(h) + o(||h||^2)
\end{align}
where $l(h) = \frac12\int\left(\langle D_xu,D_xh \rangle + \langle D_yu,D_yh \rangle  +fh \right)dxdy$ is linear in $u$. It follows that $$D_uF(h) = \frac12\int\left(\langle D_xu,D_xh \rangle + \langle D_yu,D_yh \rangle  +fh \right)dxdy$$

Comment: It's common to do an integration by parts to remove derivatives from $h.$

Comment: Thank you so much

Comment: md2perpe do you mean ${-|D_x u|^2-|D_y u|^2 +f}h$ right?